# cant use Type of information float in Zabbix 4

Tags: zabbix

I am having calculated item that should be the negative of another item. 
When I have the type unsigned, I can't change it to negative but it appears in the latest data. 
However, when I change it to float, it totally disappears from the latest data page.

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix store different types of data in different tables in the database.
For example, the table **history** store **numeric (float)**, but the table **history_uint** store **numeric (unsigned integers)**. And when you change the type of item, Zabbix web interface querying information from a different table.

Comment: thank you for the answer, how can I read the values after I change the type? Because now it disappears from the latest data page

Comment: By querying directly from the database.  But if you change type again to numeric (unsigned) latest data available? If it's true, you can create the second item with numeric (float) and use both, when you get needed amount data for the item with float type, you can delete the item with numeric (unsigned) type.

Comment: I deleted the calculated item and created new one to be float , it doesnt appear at all in latest data. If I change the type back to unsigned it will appear again

Comment: It happens because different types stored in different tables in database